# Im getting the error in that picture regarding a .kv file and could someone help me out and tell me what's going on?

Tags: python, kivy

[image]

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class MyBox(Widget):
    myInput = ObjectProperty(None)

    def printOut(self):
        print(self.myInput.text)
 
class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyBox()

if __name__=="__main__":
    myApp().run()
```

Above was Py file, down here its a .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0
<MyBox>
myInput: 'inputID'
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: 'inputID'
        Button:
            text: 'Press me'
            on_press: root.printOut()
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: At first glance from [the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file), it should be <MyBox>: with a colon and the next line should be indented. But I don't know Kivy.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rup said, you need to ident the `myInput` line and add a colon to `<MyBox>`. And also, to get your code working, you will need to get rid of these quotes in `inputID`.

So you kv file has to look like this:

```
#:kivy 1.0
<MyBox>:
    myInput: inputID
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: inputID
        Button:
            text: 'Press me'
            on_press: root.printOut()
```